# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be used inside of a react function component... useEffect, redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, graphql, apollo

I encountered a problem with my react application related to hooks. Technologies being used: React, Redux, Apollo, ChakraUI.

Here is the React component that is troubling me:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Flex, Container, Heading, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { connect, useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { State } from "../state/store";
import { fetchRecipes } from "../state/recipe/actions";

interface RecipesListProps {}

const RecipesList: React.FC<RecipesListProps> = ({}) => {

  const recipes = useSelector<State>(
    (state) => state.recipe.recipes
  ) as State["recipe"]["recipes"];

  const loading = useSelector<State>(
    (state) => state.recipe.loading
  ) as State["recipe"]["loading"];

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchRecipes());
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <h1>Loading....</h1>;
  }
  return (
    <Flex
      m="auto"
      mt="5rem"
      w="50%"
      direction="column"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
    >
      <Heading>Your Recipes</Heading>
      <Flex mt="2rem" direction="column" w="100%" padding="0" gridGap="2rem">
        {recipes &&
          recipes.map((recipe) => (
            <Container
              key={recipe.id}
              bg="orange.100"
              borderRadius="0.2rem"
              padding="1rem"
              maxW="100%"
            >
              <Text fontSize="xl" fontWeight="bold">
                {recipe.title}
              </Text>
              <Text>{recipe.description}</Text>
            </Container>
          ))}
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default RecipesList;
```

Notice the use of the `useEffect()` hook. This is the error I am getting:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I am pretty sure I am disobeying rule number, 2 i.e. I am breaking the Rules of Hooks. As soon as I take the `useEffect()` call out of the component, it doesn't throw an error.

Could someone please give some guidance as to what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

**Edit:**

The `fetchRecipes` function is a Redux thunk function that fetches recipes from a graphql server

**Update:**

I have been hacking away at a solution to this problem. I replaced the `dispatch(fetchRecipes())` call with a `console.log("hello world")`, and it worked perfectly!

This is boggling my mind! Is this a problem with the `fetchRecipes` function?

**Edit:**

Here's the code for the `fetchRecipes` function:

```
export const fetchRecipes = () => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchRecipesPending());
    const { data } = useRecipesQuery();
    const errors = data?.recipes.errors;
    const recipes = data?.recipes.recipes;
    if (errors?.length) {
      dispatch(fetchRecipesFailure(errors));
    } else {
      dispatch(fetchRecipesSuccess(recipes));
    }
  };
};
```

`useRecipesQuery` is a custom hook that was auto generated using the `graphql-codegen` library. It builds up on the `useQuery` hook from the `@apollo/client` library.

Comment: What does `fetchRecipes` do?

Comment: I added a small description of the ```fetchRecipes``` function. Let me know if you need to know more... thanks so much!

Comment: By the way, I am not using Redux Toolkit for this project, just letting you know

Comment: Please share the actual code for `fetchRecipes`. I am about to bet that you are using a hook in there and thus are breaking the rule of hooks.
Off topic, you really *should* be using Redux Toolkit. It is the official recommendation for every Redux code for years by now.

Comment: In fact, I am using a hook in ```fetchRecipes```! I'll share the code for it right away!

Comment: @phry I have dived into Redux Toolkit and I loved its ability to automatically generate action creators... I'm probably going to use it in future projects. Quick question if you don't mind, does Redux Toolkit add any performance benefits or is it simply used for better code?

Comment: Aha! Now I understand the problem... I can only use a react hook inside a function component or a custom hook. Thanks so much @phry! Do you have any thoughts on an alternative to my current implementation?

Comment: use the query in your component and pass the data in as an argument?

Comment: as for performance benefits - there might be a few fewer updated objects by using immer instead of doing immutability by hand, but it should just be pretty much the same

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` needs a little rewrite. You are dispatching the function `fetchRecipes` which in itself is a hook, but the thing dispatched should be a plain "action" (using Redux terminology here). So I guess we can fix that by breaking up your fetchRecipes fn.

A snippet of the component would now look like following:

```
const { data } = useRecipesQuery();

useEffect(() => {
  if (!data) {
    dispatch(fetchRecipesPending()) // I only assume you fetch on render
  }
  if (data?.recipes?.errors) {
    dispatch(fetchRecipesFailure(data?.recipes.errors)
  }
  if (data?.recipes?.recipes) {
    dispatch(fetchRecipesSuccess(data?.recipes?.recipes)))
  }
}, [data]);
```

Now it should be fine AND more readable. Either way, as some has already suggested, I would think about using some more standardised way like using Redux w/ Thunks or Sagas, or, even better - I see you might be doing a GQL query - if so, just use a hook for it and handle the data with Apollo Client.